# What are good ways to solve a strange data retrieval issue in elastic search?

Tags: elasticsearch

I've got a strange issue with an elastic search server.

The elastic search version is 1.6. 'records' is the name of the type. The url for the search is http://some.domain:9200/user/records/_search. The field mapping for 'un' is string.

The following query which been working for *years* is *sometimes* failing depending on the value of {someId} newer ids fail, old ones work. The data is there it's just not being found ...

```
{
  "from": 0,
  "size": 1,
  "sort": {
    "un": "desc",
    "_score": "desc"
  },
  "query": {
    "query_string": {
      "query": "un:\"{someId}\"",
      "fields": [
        "id",
        "un",
        "e",
        "fn",
        "ln",
        "bn",
        "jt",
        "sy",
        "c",
        "st",
        "p",
        "fbid",
        "lnid"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

After doing some diagnostics I discovered the following query always works whether or not {someId} is old or new ...

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "query_string": {
            "default_field": "records.un",
            "query": "{someId}"
          }
        }
      ],
      "must_not": [],
      "should": []
    }
  },
  "from": 0,
  "size": 10,
  "sort": [],
  "aggs": {}
}
```

This is a sample document that matches with the second query and fails with the first.

```
{
    "un": "xxxxxxx.xxxxxxx",
    "e": "xxxxxxx",
    "pswd": "xxxxxxx",
    "fn": "xxxxxxx",
    "ln": "xxxxxxx",
    "bn": "xxxxxxx",
    "jt": "",
    "sy": "xxxxxxx",
    "urole": "User",
    "id": "xxxxxxx",
    "status": "1",
    "lld": "201704280016",
    "cd": "201702100132",
    "md": "201704280549",
    "cc": "0",
    "p": "",
    "logo": "",
    "mlogo": "",
    "ad": "201702100132",
    "com": "xxxxxxx",
    "rr": "true",
    "sid": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
    "fbidp": "",
    "lnidp": "",
    "role": "Lots of data is in this one",
    "dim": "",
    "drm": "",
    "drcm": "xxxxxxx",
    "drcfbm": "xxxxxxx",
    "drclnm": "xxxxxxx",
    "as": "false",
    "apr": "true",
    "iuid": "xxxxxxx",
    "vcount": "9",
    "pplatform": "",
    "pname": "",
    "pid": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
    "preciept": "",
    "ms": "Free"
}
```

I'm thinking that reindexing the server might solve the issue. What are good ways to solve strange data retrieval issues in elastic search?

Comment: Can you show a document that is supposed to match but doesn't?

Comment: before reindexing think about recent changes. If it has been working since years, something must have changed. Have you updated your ES, have you changed the way you index data. Can you validate your query manually with the document it was supposed to match with ?

Comment: @krrish Not much has changed recently. Last change was a long while ago.

Comment: @Val Added sample document.

Comment: What version of ES are you running? Is `records` the name of your type?

Comment: And what's the type of your `un` field?

Comment: @Val Elastic Search server is 1.6. Type is record.

Comment: @KeithJohnHutchison Can you provide mapping of `un` field?

Comment: @val un is a string field.

Comment: @avr. un is a string field.

Comment: ok, but analyzed or not?

Comment: There is significant difference between your first (`"query": "un:\"{someId}\""`) query and second (`"query": "{someId}"`) query. In former query as you are wrapping `someId` in quotes it will search for exact phrase i.e if you have `xxx.yyy` then it will look for whole id including dot(`.`) so id will be matched only when id doesn't contains dot where as in latter query your `someId` will be analyzed i.e `xxx.yyy` will be tokenized into two strings (`xxx` and `yyy`) and it will be matched if you have dot.

Comment: @avr How would I change "query": "un:\"xxxxxxx.xxxxxxx\"" to find the document where the value of un is "xxxxxxx.xxxxxxx". To treat the dot as an ordinary character?

Comment: You need to change mappings of `un` field. If you are not doing any full-text search queries on `un` then I'd suggest you to make it `not_analyzed`. Otherwise you need to use different analyzer like `whitespace` instead of default `standard analyzer`. I'd really suggest to go with former solution as it(structured `exact` fields) is more efficient than latter

Comment: Thanks @avr. You've effectively answered my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is significant difference between your first (`"query": "un:\"{someId}\""`) query and second (`"query": "{someId}"`) query. In former query as you are wrapping `someId` in quotes as a result it will search for `exact phrase` i.e if you have `xxx.yyy` then it will look for whole id including dot(`.`) so id will be matched only when id doesn't contains dot where as in latter query your `someId` will be `analyzed` i.e `xxx.yyy` will be tokenized into two strings (`xxx` and `yyy`) and it will be matched if you have dot.

You need to change mappings of `un` field. If you are not doing any full-text search queries on `un` then I'd suggest you to make it `not_analyzed`. Otherwise you need to use different analyzer like `whitespace` instead of default `standard analyzer`. I'd really suggest to go with former solution as it(structured `exact` fields) is more efficient than latter.